# Prevent Multiple Concurrent Logins in Codeigniter From Different Browsers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

It's a common request or recommendation that a web application does not allow a user to have more than one session active at a time. In other words, after a user logs into an application, he should not be permitted to open a different type of browser (or use another computer) to log in again until his first session has ended. If the user tries to log in again, the application should expire previous sessions. I am trying to achieve this feat to no avail. Any help or recommendations would be appreciated.

Btw: My PHP Codeigniter background is not solid.

I have tried using a tutorial from here

https://blog.lucideus.com/2018/03/prevent-multiple-concurrent-logins-in.html

it suggests a resolution but when I tried, I get HTTP error 500

My controller:

```
function validate_login() {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $credential = array('email' => $email, 'password' => 
sha1($password));

  // Checking login credential for staff
    $query = $this->db->get_where('staff', $credential);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $this->session->set_userdata('staff_login', '1');
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_user_id', $row- 
>staff_id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('name', $row->name);
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'staff');
        redirect(site_url('staff/dashboard'), 'refresh');
    }

    $clientstatus['status'] =NULL;
    $credentialandstatus = array_merge($credential,$clientstatus);
    // Checking login credential for client
    $query = $this->db->get_where('client', $credentialandstatus);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $this->session->set_userdata('client_login', '1');
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_user_id', $row- 
 >client_id);

        //custom code for preventing multiple concurrent logins
        $sessionData = $this->session->all_userdata();
        $client_id = $sessionData['client_id']; 
        $sessionId=session_id();
        $this->crud_model->setSession($client_id, $sessionId);

        //ends

        $this->session->set_userdata('name', $row->name);
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'client');
        $client_fund = $this->crud_model->get_fund($row- 
>client_id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('fund', $client_fund);

        redirect(site_url('client/dashboard'), 'refresh');
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', 
 get_phrase('invalid_login'));
    redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
  }
```

My Model is this simple:

```
 function setSession($client_id, $sessionId){

    //Get previous mapped session ID
    $oldSessionId = $this->db-select("session_id")- 
>where(array('client_id'=>$client_id))->get("client")- 
>row('session_id');

 //Destroy session which was mapped to previous user
    $this->db-where('id',array('id'=>$oldSessionId));
    $this->db->delete('ci_sessions', $sessionData);


   //Map new session ID to the new user
    $this->db->where('client_id', $client_id);
    $this->db->update('client', array('session_id'=>$session_id));


   }
```

My desired result is as stated on the title.

Comment: **a 500 error could be nearly anything and isn't really useful to us** enable error reporting and db debug. i would also advise against this, i have worked with firms where security is a big concern and even they didn't care about users having multiple sessions nor does google, or amazon.

Comment: In a simple way, you can store the status of a user in the database with login info.

Comment: @SonuBamniya Generally that is what the code above is supposed but somehow, it isn't working. Maybe something is wrong with my code, but thing, is what i do not  know.